# keychain/ssh-agent loading only one key

Tags: linux, ssh, ssh-agent

My ~/.profile contains the following:

```
SSHAGENT=/usr/bin/ssh-agent
SSHAGENTARGS="-s"
if [ -z "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" -a -x "$SSHAGENT" ]; then
 eval `$SSHAGENT $SSHAGENTARGS`
 eval `keychain --eval id_rsa git-key`
fi
```

As expected, I am prompted for a password on login and ssh-agent is started. However, it ends up only having the key id_rsa (verified via "ssh-add -l"). It doesn't load git-key into ssh-agent even though it and id_rsa have the same password. If I then run:

```
eval `keychain --eval id_rsa git-key`
```

from the command line git-key is also loaded and ssh-agent now has both keys.

My question is, why is only one of the two keys getting loaded on login?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doh! I use git to keep my .profile and other configs synced between several machines. My latest git merge didn't merge the way I expected so I had two different lines with calls to keychain only one of which was getting executed.